# How can I import in Java top execute scanner.in

Tags: java

```
package com.Input;

public class Input {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner value = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(value.nextLine());
    }

}
```

I am trying to get input from keyboard in Java . But I could not import the code. Please help me to find the import above program and find the bug in the above program

Comment: It is `java.util.Scanner`, which is what you need

Comment: Hint: the next time try your favorite engine first. Googling for "java scanner", the first hit is http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html 
Meaning: you really do not need stack overflow for such basic things. You will be even **faster** when learning to use the internet first. Worse, some people might regard your question to be "bad", causing downvotes; and loss of reputation.

Comment: Moreover, IMHO, `Scanner` is best used, if it is provided input in the form of buffered stream, instead of byte stream, like `Scanner input = new Scanner ( new BufferedReader ( new InputStreamReader ( System.in ) ) );`. For this to work, you need another import, `java.io.*;`

Answer (score 1):

add `import java.util.Scanner` after between `package ...` and `public class Input{` to import `Scanner`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the Scanner class from `java.util.Scanner`. So add the following after the line: `package com.Input;`

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```